# Were SpaceX's early launches insured?

Tags: spacex, cost, falcon-1

SpaceX's first three launches (of the Falcon 1) were failures, with the fourth launch being a success. Rockets are generally insured in order to protect the payload investment, but those three failures [apparently drove the company to the edge of bankruptcy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX).

My question is, who (if anyone) insured SpaceX's first launches?

Comment: It seems unlikely anyone would insure that risk.

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, but the first three falcon 1 launches carried US government payloads (which IIRC are not insured as a matter of policy) and the fourth carried a dummy payload. Only the final launch actually carried a commercial payload.